# Assign a index value to the list element value dynamically in sortable JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to have sortable list where I need to set the value of every list element to its index value, for. ex. if element ex1 becomes second then I need to set a value for it of 1 (counting from 0), if element ex2 becomes third then value of 2, and so on. I'm trying to achieve that by setting value inside the update method of sortable. But every time I'm trying to do run that it is not updating the value state, it stacks on default initial value.

Here's Js fiddle you can check it (just change the order on the list and check values inside devtools, look how it stays the same).

```
const orderedList = $('li');

$('ul').sortable({
  update: function() {
    orderedList.each(function(idx) {
      $(this).attr("value", idx);
    })
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/896382/

Comment: li tags haven't any value attribute and can not have.

Comment: have you tried this function:  orderedList.each(function(idx,value) {
      $(this).attr("value", idx);
    })

Comment: try this instead 
orderedList.each(function(idx){

 $(this).text(idx);
 
})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just update your function, basically you are defining a const value globally,so value is not updated. when you are modifying a collection.

```
$('li').each(function(idx){
  $(this).attr("value", idx);
})

const getValue = $('li:first-child').attr("value");
$('h4').text(getValue);

$('ul').sortable({
  update: function() {
    var _li= $('li');
    _li.removeAttr("value");
    _li.each(function(idx) {
      var currentObj=$(this);
      console.log(currentObj.text());
      $(this).attr("value", idx);
    })
  }
});
```

see updated code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Negirox/57dme0as/)

Comment: You're right, but I don't understand why I need to remove the attribute in order to update it. Thank you!

Comment: just for the safer side :)

Answer (score 0):

Your current code will update the value of the list, you can see that in the developer window. I have placed an image of the same below.

[image]

If you are looking for the text to change then you can use the below code instead

You can try

```
orderedList.each(function(idx,value) {$(this).text(idx); })
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g361hfcv/)

Answer (score 0):

What I Know from your question, please try this code

```js
$('ul').sortable({
  update: function() {
    const orderedList = $('li');
    orderedList.each(function(idx) {
      $(this).find('span').html("Example " + (idx + 1));
    });
    const getValue = $('li:first-child').find('input').val();
    $('h4').text(getValue);
  }
});
```

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span>Example 1</span>
      <input type='hidden' value='0'>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span>Example 2</span>
      <input type='hidden' value='1'>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span>Example 3</span>
      <input type='hidden' value='2'>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<h4></h4>
```